# block this special characters using query `~ #$^+|\ []{}<>

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I want to block some special characters from entering in text box.
`~ #$^+|\ []{}<> these are the characters i would like to prevent from user inputting. Can any one suggest a solution or reg ex.

Comment: Possible duplicate question of [Disabling some special characters in text area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991259/disabling-some-special-characters-in-text-area)

Comment: If you feel that your question is a basic common programming problem, that is much likely that it has been asked before. So it would be nice to use search instead of asking a fresh duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function some(){
var input = document.getElementById('one').value;
var one = input.replace(/[(\\^`~#\$\^\+\|\\\[\]{}<>)]/g,"");
document.getElementById('one').value=one;
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" oninput="some()" id="one"  >
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions that smell like a duplicate in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" pattern="[^`~#\$\^\+\|\\\[\]{}<>]+">
```